# Как обойти/отключить изоляцию udp клиента на Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, сеть, udp

Делаю простенькую Lan игру на android на unity. Для обнаружения устройств в локальной сети использую udp broadcast как в этом примере https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast. Когда телефоны подключены к одной сети через роутер или другой телефон с точкой доступа все работает правильно. Но когда на одном телефоне включена точка доступа, а другой подключен к ней, тот у которого включена точка доступа не отправляет ничего другому, хотя принимает так же хорошо. Никаких ошибок при отправке не происходит, запросы просто где-то растворяются. Как я понял это происходит из-за изоляции точки доступа для защиты от взлома. Так вот как все таки отправить udp broadcast в таком случае?

Comment: `Как я понял это происходит из-за изоляции точки доступа для защиты от взлома.` как именно вы это поняли?